# Equivalent of Partial Matching XLOOKUP in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

The following code will tell me if there are partial matches (via the True values in the final column):

```
import pandas as pd

x = {'Non-Suffix' : ['1234567', '1234568', '1234569', '1234554'], 'Suffix' : ['1234567:C', '1234568:VXCF', '1234569-01', '1234554-01:XC']}
x = pd.DataFrame(x)
x['"Non-Suffix" Partial Match in "Suffix"?'] = x.apply(lambda row: row['Non-Suffix'] in row['Suffix'], axis=1)
x
```

[image]

However, if I re-arrange the values in the second column, I'll get False values:

```
x = {'Non-Suffix' : ['1234567', '1234568', '1234569', '1234554'], 'Suffix' : ['1234568:VXCF', '1234567:C', '1234554-01:XC', '1234569-01']}
x = pd.DataFrame(x)
x['"Non-Suffix" Partial Match in "Suffix"?'] = x.apply(lambda row: row['Non-Suffix'] in row['Suffix'], axis=1)
x
```

[image]

Is there a way I can get the second block of code to find these partial matches even if they're not in the same row?

Also, instead of 'True/False' values, is there a way for me to have the value of 'Partial Match Exists!' instead of True, and 'Partial Match Does Not Exist!' instead of False?

Comment: The dataframe `x` in the two codes are different. The code runs correctly

Comment: 1234567 exists in row 0, while 1234567:C exists in row 1.  I'd like to be able to find the partial match (based on the Non-Suffix column).  I'm looking for a new solution, which is why I posted on SO... @PTQuoc

Comment: So you want to check if every row in 'Non-Suffix' is contained in `column` Suffix?

Comment: Yes, if ```Non-Suffix``` values exist somewhere in ```column``` Suffix @PTQuoc

Comment: If it does, indicate 'Partial Match Found!' instead of ```True``` and 'Partial Match Not Found!' in place of ```False```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join the `Non-Suffix` column value with `|` then use `Series.str.contains` to check if contain any value

```py
x['"Non-Suffix" Partial Match in "Suffix"?'] = x['Suffix'].str.contains('|'.join(x['Non-Suffix']))
```

```
print(x)

  Non-Suffix         Suffix  "Non-Suffix" Partial Match in "Suffix"?
0    1234567   1234568:VXCF                                     True
1    1234568      1234567:C                                     True
2    1234569  1234554-01:XC                                     True
3    1234554     1234569-01                                     True
```

Above solution checks if `Suffix` contains any of `Non-Suffix`, if you want to do the reverse, you might do

```py
x['"Non-Suffix" Partial Match in "Suffix"?'] = x['Non-Suffix'].apply(lambda v: x['Suffix'].str.contains(v).any())
```

```
print(x)

  Non-Suffix         Suffix  "Non-Suffix" Partial Match in "Suffix"?
0        879   1234568:VXCF                                    False
1    1234568      1234567:C                                     True
2    1234569  1234554-01:XC                                     True
3    1234554     1234569-01                                     True
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Instead of True, how could I get it to say ```Partial Match Exists!``` and instead of False, how could I get it to say ```Partial Match Does Not Exist!```? @Ynjxsjmh

Comment: @HelpMeCode You can try `replace({True: 'Partial Match Exists!'})`

Comment: Would that be a new line of code?

Where would I input it into ```x['"Non-Suffix" Partial Match in "Suffix"?'] = x['Suffix'].str.contains('|'.join(x['Non-Suffix']))```? @Ynjxsjmh

Comment: Just add `.replace` after is enough.

Comment: Awesome!! What about the ```False```?  There aren't any in this example, but would it also just be a ```.replace({False: 'Partial Match Does Not Exists!'})```?

Comment: @HelpMeCode You can add False as key to extend the True key.

Comment: @Ynjxsjmh: I don't think the code is correct. Or I miss understand the author explanation. If the author expect is `Non-Suffix` is a substring of a `list` in `Suffix` then your code is not correct. Try to modify index 0  `Non-Suffix` with '879', the output is not correct. `x = {'Non-Suffix' : ['89879', '1234568', '1234569', '1234554'], 'Suffix' : ['1234568:VXCF', '1234567:C', '1234554-01:XC', '1234569-01']}
`

Comment: @PTQuoc What's the expected output in your understanding?

Comment: @Ynjxsjmh: My understanding to the author question is: check if every row in column `Non-Suffix` is a substring in the column `Suffix`. If this is the case, then your answer is reversed. Example this data `x = {'Non-Suffix' : ['89879', '1234568', '1234569', '1234554'], 'Suffix' : ['1234568:VXCF', '1234567:C', '1234554-01:XC', '1234569-01']}` Then my output expect should be `False, True, True, True` as `89879` is not a substring of any row in column `Suffix`

Comment: @PTQuoc Seems you are right.

Comment: @Ynjxsjmh has the correct understanding!

In just playing around with the data frames, if I add another value to ```Suffix```, the code will error out because the two arrays are no longer the same length.  

Is there a way around this?  In practice, the two lists I'd be comparing will not always be the same length.

Comment: @HelpMeCode If `Suffix` contains list value, it will be much complicated, you might need `explode` first then `groupby` back. If `Non-Suffix` also contains list, that would be super complicated.

Comment: Would you suggest I post a new question? @Ynjxsjmh

Comment: @HelpMeCode Yes, at least you didn't mention list condition in this question.

Comment: Ok I'll post a new one, thank you for all your wonderfulous help! @Ynjxsjmh

Comment: Last question, what do you mean by list condition? @Ynjxsjmh

Comment: @HelpMeCode If Suffix contains list value as you sad *if I add another value to Suffix*

Comment: Ah, right, that's what my new question will be about :) @Ynjxsjmh